# How to load a Cocos2d animation inside a UIViewController in UIKit based App?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

It's possible to mix in a normal xcode project for iOS in a UIViewController one animation based on cocos2d?

I'm experimenting issues with the animations done by UIImageView and I'm trying to use cocos2d instead. I've a pair of views where animations are placed.

Is possible to create a CC2dAnimationObject in order to be used in a UIViewController?

Thanks.

SOLVED -

Hi all, I'm a happy guy. I get the approach.

I've made a pair of classes one CCScoreBoardLG (names are not definitive) this class is a subclass of UIViewController and loads the EAGLView with the object OTAnimationCC2d that is the container of the animation.

The CCScoreBoardLG can be placed anywhere in a UIKit View Controller and the background is transparent in order to place the animation and see the content behind it.

Some part are hardcoded because test purposes but easily can be adapted to load any kind of animation. the animation is placed in the middle of the CCScene and is in loop mode.

Here the classes:

OTAnimationCC2d.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface OTAnimationCC2d : CCLayer{

}
+(id) scene;
@end
```

OTAnimationCC2d.m

```
#import "OTAnimationCC2d.h"


@implementation OTAnimationCC2d
+(id) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    OTAnimationCC2d *layer = [OTAnimationCC2d node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"OTScoreBoard_LG_Atlas_Team_1_4.plist"];
        CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"OTScoreBoard_LG_Atlas_Team_1_4.png"];
        [self addChild:spriteSheet];

        NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
            NSString *file;

            if (i<10)
                file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Frame_00%d.png", i];
            else if (i<100)
                file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Frame_0%d.png", i];
            else if (i<1000)
                file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Frame_%d.png", i];

            CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:file];

            [animFrames addObject:frame];
        }

        CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Frame_001.png"];
        player.rotation = -90;
        player.position = ccp(s.width/2,s.height/2);

        [spriteSheet addChild:player];

        CCAnimation *anim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animFrames delay:0.05f];
        CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
        [player runAction:repeat];
    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

CCScoreBoardLG.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "CCOTConfig.h"
#import "OTAnimationCC2d.h"

@interface CCScoreBoardLG : UIViewController
- (void)startCCLayer;
@end
```

CCScoreBoardLG.m

```
#import "CCScoreBoardLG.h"

@implementation CCScoreBoardLG
- (void) removeStartupFlicker
{
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController

        CC_ENABLE_DEFAULT_GL_STATES();
        CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
        CGSize size = [director winSize];
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"OTScoreBoardBackground.png"];
        sprite.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);
        sprite.rotation = -90;
        [sprite visit];
        [[director openGLView] swapBuffers];
        CC_ENABLE_DEFAULT_GL_STATES();

#endif
}
- (void)startCCLayer
{
    if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
        [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];


    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[self.view frame]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8    // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                        ];

    [director setOpenGLView:glView];
    [director openGLView].opaque = NO;
    [director openGLView].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)[director openGLView].layer;
    eaglLayer.opaque = NO;
    eaglLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;

    CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    const CGFloat myColor[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    eaglLayer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreate(rgb, myColor);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);

    [director openGLView].opaque = NO;
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 

#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
#else
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
#endif

    [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    [director setDisplayFPS:NO];

    [self setView:glView];

    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    [self removeStartupFlicker];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [OTAnimationCC2d scene]];

}


// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    //
    // There are 2 ways to support auto-rotation:
    //  - The OpenGL / cocos2d way
    //     - Faster, but doesn't rotate the UIKit objects
    //  - The ViewController way
    //    - A bit slower, but the UiKit objects are placed in the right place
    //

#if GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationNone
    //
    // EAGLView won't be autorotated.
    // Since this method should return YES in at least 1 orientation, 
    // we return YES only in the Portrait orientation
    //
    return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );

#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationCCDirector
    //
    // EAGLView will be rotated by cocos2d
    //
    // Sample: Autorotate only in landscape mode
    //
    if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    } else if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    }

    // Since this method should return YES in at least 1 orientation, 
    // we return YES only in the Portrait orientation
    return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );

#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    //
    // EAGLView will be rotated by the UIViewController
    //
    // Sample: Autorotate only in landscpe mode
    //
    // return YES for the supported orientations

    return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );

#else
#error Unknown value in GAME_AUTOROTATION

#endif // GAME_AUTOROTATION


    // Shold not happen
    return NO;
}

//
// This callback only will be called when GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
//
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    //
    // Assuming that the main window has the size of the screen
    // BUG: This won't work if the EAGLView is not fullscreen
    ///
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;


    if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)      
        rect = screenRect;

    else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        rect.size = CGSizeMake( screenRect.size.height, screenRect.size.width );

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    EAGLView *glView = [director openGLView];
    float contentScaleFactor = [director contentScaleFactor];

    if( contentScaleFactor != 1 ) {
        rect.size.width *= contentScaleFactor;
        rect.size.height *= contentScaleFactor;
    }
    glView.frame = rect;
}
#endif // GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

How to use. From the View where we want to place the animation CC2d:

```
CCScoreBoardLG *LG = [[CCScoreBoardLG alloc] init];
LG.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 300, 1004, 300);
[LG.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view addSubview:LG.view];
[LG startCCLayer];
```

I'm absolutely noob in CC2d and GL techniques. I'm sorry if any CC2d guru finds errors or things that are not correct. This works for me.

Comment: +1 Your solution helped me fix the same problem for me. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly. You would have to manually update all animated properties of a cocos2d node and apply the changes to the corresponding UIView properties every frame.

There's a [CCUIViewWrapper](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889) class that may help you with this, at the least it seems like a nice template that you can modify to your needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but this is the opposite that I'm trying. This wrapper seems to insert a UIView in a Cocos2d Scene. My case is the reverse, how to insert a cocos2d scene in a UIView. I've developed a cocos2d class that creates an animation. What have I do to create from my View this cocos object and add it to the view like [myView addSubview:mycocos.view]?

Answer (score 0):

CCDirector in Cocos2D 2.x is based on UIViewController.

So you can add it's view like any other UIView.